# Unrecognized option: -f apache commons CLI

Tags: spring-boot, apache-commons-cli

I get a correct result, but with the below error :

> Error while parsing the command line: Unrecognized option: -f

```
public void run(String... args){
     Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("h", "help", false, "prints the help content");
        options.addOption("f", "fileType", true, "file type");
        LoadReferenceFileRequest request=new LoadReferenceFileRequest();
       try{
          CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
          CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);
          if(commandLine.hasOption("f") && commandLine.hasOption("u") && commandLine.hasOption("d")) {
              String fileType = commandLine.getOptionValue("f");
              request.setFileType(fileType);

              String url = commandLine.getOptionValue("u");
              request.setUrl(url);

              String validDate = commandLine.getOptionValue("d");
              request.setValidDate(validDate);
              LoadReferenceFileResponse response= loadReferenceFileClientService.invoke(request);     
              System.out.println(response);
          }else {
                 HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                 formatter.printHelp( "Osmium Spa" , options );
                 System.exit(1);

       } 
       }catch(MissingOptionException e){

          //vérifie si l'option -h est présente
          boolean help = false;
          try{
             Options helpOptions = new Options();
             helpOptions.addOption("h", "help", false, "prints the help content");
             CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
             CommandLine line = parser.parse(helpOptions, args);
             if(line.hasOption("h")) help = true;
          }
          catch(Exception ex){ }
          if(!help) System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
          formatter.printHelp( "Osmium Spa" , options );
          System.exit(1);
       } 
}
```

any help please, I would like to take off this error  thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is the problem/question? Can you also add the stack trace?

Comment: I get a correct result, but i have a message error :

Error while parsing the command line: Unrecognized option: -f

Comment: Where the error is being thrown from? Which class/line?

Comment: result:   code=OK
  reason=<null>
  diagnostic=[]
Error while parsing the command line: Unrecognized option: -f

Comment: i get the error in the catch

Comment: We have to find which line of code is throwing the exception. Please temporarily update the catch block with: `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: i try it but i have the same error :(